# Copying RTF text into my AS3 program

Tags: actionscript-3, rtf

I've searched and searched, but all that pops up is "buy this, buy that".

Is there no way I can just copy text from MS-Word and be able to preserve formatting as I paste into my application? (I'm not talking about the Flash IDE here, I'm talking about sticking it in a TLF or something)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can do this in adobe air. if you can use air I'll explain how it works.... it's a bit of a pain to do unfortunately.

Comment: I'll write up a detailed answer for you tomorrow. To get you started check out : Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData and setData ... don't use rtf, instead use ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT - the reason is there is no documentation (at least I couldn't find any) on the byteArray that gets stored when you read the rtf format. Turns out that the HTML_FORMAT is easy to understand and with a regular expression or two you can copy and paste lots of things from a word doc. There are a few things I didn't try (like tables) - but lists, bold, font sizes colors etc are all doable

Comment: that's all I need !! thank's a tonne, I'll be waiting

Comment: just hoping you didn't forget or anything cuz I kinda need a solution :s  Cheers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Here is how it works. If you want to pop content from word into a TextField in flash you need to do something like this...

Once you copy from word you need to decide how to pop the content into a TextField... do you want to try and use cmd+v by doing some KeyboardEvent stuff? Do you want to have a button that says something like "Paste Content"? Either way, you'll be running some code to grab the clipboard contents and pop it into the TextField in response to some event. So in your event handler do something like this:

```
function onPasteEvent(e:SomeEventType):void{

    var pasteData:String = Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT) as String;
    if (pasteData){

       txt.htmlText = formatClipboardData(pasteData);
    }else{
          // probably nothing on clipboard
    }

}
```

Now the formatClipboardData() function will do some kind of manipulation on the data from the clipboard. You'll notice that the HTML that comes from word is full of weird stuff. You can strip some of it out, tidy it up and in some cases use some of their classes. In some code that I'm looking at I have this:

```
var s:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
s.setStyle(".MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst", {marginLeft : "10px"});
...
txt.styleSheet = s;
```

In order to indent list items from the word doc. You can use simple regular expressions to alter the html... remove unwanted attributes and tags. Here are a few examples from my formatClipboardData() function:

```
// lists were coming in as dots with some space inside a p tag so:
  replace(/<p>\·\s+(.*?)<\/p>/g, "<li>$1</li>")

// no need for the body tag:
  replace(/<body>|<\/body>/g,"")

// strip attributes from p tags:
  replace(/<p(.*?)>/g, "<p>")

etc....
```

Comment: Thanks for the huge step up from where I was, but next question is, textFields don't dispatch any PASTE events, and there's a constraint that says  you can't grab from clipboard unless your handling the PASTE event. So how do you do that? (I'd like to be able to use ctrl+v  and  right click->paste)

Comment: pretty sure you can do this with TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT and preventDefault() if you preventDefault on TEXT_INPUT you can process the input before it goes into the TextField - I tested and it fires when you do a copy and paste... using the copy menu might be trickier though... you might need to use the change event...